# Is there a modification for filling function to behave accurately

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a function using python that fulfills flood filling inside a boundary located in a grayscale image, I used the recursive solution so that the function moves in 4 directions surrounding each pixel and filling the black pixels, however I found it fills only the central column at which the point was inserted to the function. I hope anyone can help me to figure out where could be the error in my function definition to flood fill all the polygon. Kindly find my code and the result. Many thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im = cv2.imread('D:\My work\\try2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
pt = [int(h/2),int(w/2)]
print(gray[pt[0],pt[1]])
points = []
def filling(image,point): # Image must be grayscale image using 4 connectivity
    p1 =[point[0]+1,point[1]]
    p2 =[point[0]-1, point[1]]
    p3 =[point[0],point[1]+1]
    p4 =[point[0], point[1]-1]
    if (image[p1[0],p1[1]] < 200):
        image[p1[0],p1[1]] = 255
        filling(image,p1)
    elif (image[p2[0],p2[1]]<200):
        image[p2[0],p2[1]]=255
        filling(image,p2)
    elif (image[p3[0],p3[1]]<200):
        image[p3[0],p3[1]]=255
        filling(image,p3)
    elif (image[p4[0],p4[1]]<200):
        image[p4[0],p4[1]] =255
        filling(image,p4)
    return image
gray2 = filling(gray,[int(h/2),int(w/2)])

cv2.imshow('Image1',gray2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: cv2.floodFill, https://www.learnopencv.com/filling-holes-in-an-image-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: Change all the `elif`s to just `if`s?

Comment: @Miki  I know that there is already existing built in function in opencv however I would like to develop it manually

Comment: @Powercoder it doesn't change however it throw an error

Comment: You should do bounds checking on the points so that they're not less than 0 or greater than the size of the image.